# PHP Read lines in blocks in a file

Tags: php

I have a log file which contains data in Blocks. examples as below. as you can see in each block `recv_time`, `Span`, `From-Number`, `Timestamp`, `Type`, `SMS-SMSC-Number` and `Content` are repeated. i want to get their values in php and save in a database table. each block has its own values. your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
----SMS_START----
recv_time:2014-10-09 18:32:39
Span: 1
From-Number: +1347XXXXXXX
Timestamp: 14/10/09 18:32:16 96
Type: PDU
SMS-SMSC-Number: +12404492163
Content: Thanks,


----SMS_END----

----SMS_START----
recv_time:2014-10-09 18:35:00
Span: 1
From-Number: +1347XXXXXXX
Timestamp: 14/10/09 18:34:37 96
Type: PDU
SMS-SMSC-Number: +12404492163
Content: Thanks


----SMS_END----

----SMS_START----
recv_time:2014-10-10 18:04:05
Span: 1
From-Number: +28809090
Timestamp: 14/10/09 23:03:42 96
Type: PDU
SMS-SMSC-Number: +12404492163
Content: AT&T Free Msg: If this was done in error, please call 611 or 800.901.9878.


----SMS_END----
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code do you have? What approach have you considered might work for your scenario? We cannot guide you this way within this Q&A style site, we can only assist directly with code you provide which you need assistance with.

Comment: This is so far i have done. it returns the values but i still could not figur out how to save these values in separate variables.                                                     <?php
$fd = fopen ("/var/log/asterisk/recvsms/recvsms_log", "r");

while (!feof ($fd))
{
   $buffer = fgets($fd, 4096);
        $lines[] =  $buffer;
#echo $buffer;
}

$row = count($lines);

for ($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
{
$a = explode(":",$lines[$i],2);
print_r($a[1]);

}

fclose($fd)

?>

Comment: @Khan: You will need to post the current state of your PHP code (the relevant portions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this its working

```
<?
$file = file("data.txt");
foreach($file as $key => $value)
{
$filter_value = trim($value);
if($filter_value!="" && $filter_value!="----SMS_START----" && $filter_value!="----SMS_END----"){
$new_array[] = $value;
$my_array = array_chunk($new_array, 7);
}
}
$count = count($my_array);
for($I=0;$I<$count;$I++){
foreach($my_array[$I] as $key => $value){
$ss = explode(":", $value);
$mm_array[$I][$ss[0]] = str_replace($ss[0].":", "", $value);
}
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($mm_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [recv_time] => 2014-10-09 18:32:39

        [Span] =>  1

        [From-Number] =>  +1347XXXXXXX

        [Timestamp] =>  14/10/09 18:32:16 96

        [Type] =>  PDU

        [SMS-SMSC-Number] =>  +12404492163

        [Content] =>  Thanks,

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [recv_time] => 2014-10-09 18:35:00

        [Span] =>  1

        [From-Number] =>  +1347XXXXXXX

        [Timestamp] =>  14/10/09 18:34:37 96

        [Type] =>  PDU

        [SMS-SMSC-Number] =>  +12404492163

        [Content] =>  Thanks

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [recv_time] => 2014-10-10 18:04:05

        [Span] =>  1

        [From-Number] =>  +28809090

        [Timestamp] =>  14/10/09 23:03:42 96

        [Type] =>  PDU

        [SMS-SMSC-Number] =>  +12404492163

        [Content] =>  AT&T Free Msg: If this was done in error, please call 611 or    800.901.9878.

    )

)
```

You can now easily inserted to the database

Enjoy!

Comment: above is my log file and get new data time by time. is there any way i can read only new added entries (block) in the file? instead of start reading file from start to the end of file. this file size will be in GBs soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess you have no code, here is some pseudocode:

```
entries = {}
entry = empty
foreach lines in file do
    if line is startTag then
        entry = {} -- initilize empty entry
    elseif line is endTag then
        entries.add(entry)
    else
        entry.set(line.to(':'), line.till(':'))
    end
end
```

This is the algorithm (no optimization and error prone).

Comment: when i run my code i get result in following format          2014-10-09 18:32:39
 1
 +1347XXXXXXX
 14/10/09 18:32:16 96
 PDU
 +12404492163
 Thanks,                                                         2014-10-09 18:35:00
 1
 +1347XXXXXXX
 14/10/09 18:34:37 96
 PDU
 +12404492163
 Thanks                                                      2014-10-09 23:04:05
 1
 +28809090
 14/10/09 23:03:42 96
 PDU
 +12404492163
 AT&T Free Msg: If this was done in error, please call 611 or 800.901.9878.                                                here i want to save these values on variables.